# What is the '...' operator in the context of a list in dart?

Tags: dart

I have come upon the following code...

```
var list = [...otherList];
```

I tried googling this and I actually had trouble finding it.

What does the '...' operator do here?

Comment: Spread... Without it `list` would be list of lists with single element `otherList`

Answer (score 2):

The spread operator is discussed in the [Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists). If you haven't read the whole language tour from beginning to end *recently*, please do so. It's well worth the time (yours, *and* ours).